Typecast CUdeviceptr to uchar** in cuda access throws illegal memory access error 700
We allocated the memory for CUdeviceptr for v1 object and type cast to uchar** type.
CUdeviceptr v1;
checkCudaResult(cuMemAlloc((CUdeviceptr*)&v1, 16));
checkCudaErrors(cudaMemset((void*)v1, 1, 16));
uchar** v1char = (uchar**)v1;
foo_double<<<4,4>>>(v1char);
checkCudaResult(cuMemFree(v1));

The above code throws an error of illegal memory access when v1char is accessed inside the kernel like the following,
_global__ void foo_double(uchar** val) {
  unsigned int tid = threadIdx_x;
  unsigned int bid = blockIdx_x * blockDim_x + tid;
  uchar* val_ = val[bid];
  printf("%d:%d\n", bid,*val_);
}

No compilation or build error, is there any correct way to typecast v1 (device pointer) to uchar** pointer and access the address correctly?

foo_double treats val as if *v1 were a pointer, but it isn't. A similar situation: char a[16]; char** p = (char**) a; char* p2 = a[0]; char c = *p2;. If you don't understand why that won't work, read more about arrays and pointers in your favourite C++ book.

What is strict aliasing rule

@user12002570 I don't think strict aliasing UB applies here. OP rather doesn't seem to understand pointers on a more basic level. Memory is filled with integer ones and these ones are interpreted as an address and dereferenced.

@paleonix Adding another dupe for that. The strict aliasing rule does apply here though.

@user12002570 The host and device code are compiled independently and the access on the device does only go through one type of pointer. Similar casts are done in low level CUDA libraries all the time, e.g. to facilitate vectorized loads/stores using CUDA's char2 type (basically a struct of two chars + alignment) on a properly aligned char*. Mentioning strict aliasing in this context is worth a comment, but it is not a dupe.

If you really need/want to use the CUDA driver API, I propose you take a look at the official vectorAddDrv sample to see how you are expected to work with it. As a beginner I would rather recommend you use the CUDA runtime API, i.e. cudaMalloc(). See the vectorAdd sample for comparison.

OP is indeed confused about some basic C++ principles, see here.  The storage size for an array of pointers is being incorrectly calculated.  That is not unique or specific to CUDA.
